# Not able start Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
$mongo
```

Getting error:

```
--------------
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-01-17T20:21:16.583+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-01-17T20:21:16.584+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Attached the screen shot [image: SS of Error]

Answer (score 0):

1. Similar issue was discussed [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mongo-no-longer-connects)

In that case removing the below file solve the problem:

```
sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

followed by launching mongo service again, solve the problem

2. Similar problem, with different source was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479384/mongodb-permission-denied-for-socket-tmp-mongodb-27017-sock)

In this case `/tmp` permission got corrupted and it was solved by fixing `/tmp` by running:

```
sudo chown root:root /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Another option might be that `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` is not owned by `mongodb` - which can be fixed by (note that solution #1 above which delete the file should solve the wrong ownership issue as well):

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Note that: providing relevant logs, might help identifying the problem. e.g.

```
tail -30 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

Comment: @NaveenKumar - did my answer solve your problem?